# MS SQL выборка по datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

не могу понять логики. ковыряю чужой код там скл запрос вида

```
select * from
db
where DATE_IZMER>='01.11.2015'
 and DATE_IZMER<='30.11.2015'
```

пытаюсь выполнить в менеджере получаю

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

привожу к виду `DATE_IZMER>=cast('2015-11-01' as datetime)` нет данных вообще

`getdate` отдает `03.12.2015 15:04:59`

Comment: смог повторить Вашу ошибку, что бы работало надо написать так: `select * from table where column>='2015.1.11'` в Вашем случае формат может отличаться, я так предполагаю зависит от настроек сервера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В SQL Server есть всего [два формата литералов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) даты/времени, не привязанных к локали. Это

- `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`
- `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`

... где в [...] - необязательная часть

все остальные привязаны к текущей локали (включая `YYYY-MM-DD` - его ломает `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN`)

Т.е. если очень хочется явно вшить дату в SQL, то стоит использовать формат `YYYYMMDD`:

```sql
select * from
db
where DATE_IZMER >= '20151101'
  and DATE_IZMER <= '20151130'
 -- если в  DATE_IZMER есть время, то лучше DATE_IZMER < '20151201'
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db
WHERE DATE_IZMER >= '2015-11-01' AND DATE_IZMER <= '2015-11-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ZNTF_Data2 A where A.ZNTF_datetime between '20190701' and '20190815' order by A.ZNTF_datetime
```